# Using timer to refresh interface, keep getting "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

Tags: c#, mysql, timer

I've been using a timer to refresh the listview on my application, but after half a second, I get the error message at first `try/catch method` in `RefreshPlot()` in **PlotComponent.cs**:

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in Marketplace.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated
>   with this Connection which must be closed first.

What is this down to? I'm tried using `using` and `try/catch`, so I am not really clear on the mistake I could be making. When I disable the timer everything works well. But I need to access the database every 0.5 seconds in order to refresh the listview.

If I am not doing it the correct way is there anything else I can do?

Code is as follows:

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Reset lists
    SetPlotList(_filterPlotReference);

    // Refresh lists
    Refresh();
}

public void Refresh()
{
    var myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer.Elapsed += RefreshPlotList;
    myTimer.Interval = 500;
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
}

public void RefreshPlotList(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    PlotComponent.RefreshPlot();
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterTextBox.Text) &&
            (!Regex.IsMatch(FilterTextBox.Text, "[^0-9]")))
        {
            _filterPlotReference = Convert.ToInt32(FilterTextBox.Text);
        }
    });
    SetPlotList(_filterPlotReference);
    FocusPlotItem(_focusPlotReference);
}

public void SetPlotList(int filterReference)
{
    // Fill plot list view
    List<PlotComponent.PlotList> plotList = PlotComponent.SelectPlotLists(filterReference);

    // Find the plot list item in the new list
    PlotComponent.PlotList selectPlotList =
        plotList.Find(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.PlotId) == _focusPlotReference);

    Dispatcher.Invoke(
        (() =>
        {
            PlotListView.ItemsSource = plotList;
            if (selectPlotList != null)
            {
                PlotListView.SelectedItem = selectPlotList;
            }
        }));

    int jobSum = 0;
    int bidSum = 0;
    foreach (PlotComponent.PlotList item in PlotListView.Items)
    {
        jobSum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Jobs);
        bidSum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Bids);
    }

    // Determine job/bid list ratio
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        new ThreadStart(() => JobBidRatioTextBlock.Text = jobSum + " jobs - " + bidSum + " bids"));
}

private void FocusPlotItem(int focusPlotReference)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(
        (() =>
        {
            PlotComponent.PlotList plotList =
                PlotListView.Items.OfType<PlotComponent.PlotList>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.PlotId) == focusPlotReference);
            if (plotList == null) return;
            //get visual container
            var container = PlotListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(plotList) as ListViewItem;
            if (container == null) return;
            container.IsSelected = true;
            container.Focus();
        }));
}
```

**DbConnect.cs**

http://pastebin.com/pZ0PGrg1

**PlotComponent.cs**

http://pastebin.com/xiRhKyMM

Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to lock timer till it finishes its work:

```
bool timerRunning = false; // define it as a global variable

// then in your timer process add this easy check
public void RefreshPlotList(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(timerRunning) return; // return if it is busy
    timerRunning = true;  // set it to busy

    PlotComponent.RefreshPlot();
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterTextBox.Text) &&
            (!Regex.IsMatch(FilterTextBox.Text, "[^0-9]")))
        {
            _filterPlotReference = Convert.ToInt32(FilterTextBox.Text);
        }
    });
    SetPlotList(_filterPlotReference);
    FocusPlotItem(_focusPlotReference);

    timerRunning = false;  // reset it for next time use
}
```

**P.S**: I edited the other answer by adding (exactly) this answer, then I got rejected, the peer review says

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no
>   sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an
>   answer

I have no doubt that they did read the edit and evaluate it, not to mention the fact that it doesn't fit in a comment, so here I post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you disable the timer until the RefreshPlotList function finishes?

May be at the start of the function disable the timer and at the end of RefreshPlotList function Enable the timer. I guess RefreshPlotList function is taking more than .5 seconds and another call is made before the current one is finished.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I would disable it?